# Everything else starting on Hadoop pseudo-distributed except namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop2, namenode

I have Hadoop 2.9.0 on Ubuntu at

```
/usr/local/hadoop
```

But when I try `start-dfs.sh`
No error is shown while starting namenode
But when I type `jps`, only

```
10900 SecondaryNameNode
11047 Jps
10696 DataNode
```

Seams to have started, not namenode

Things tried:
=> Removed temp files and formatted namenode `hadoop namenode -format`

terminal:

```
blaze@blazian:/tmp$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
blaze@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-blaze-namenode-blazian.out
blaze@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-blaze-datanode-blazian.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
blaze@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-blaze-secondarynamenode-blazian.out
blaze@blazian:/tmp$ jps
10900 SecondaryNameNode
11047 Jps
10696 DataNode
```

Comment: Check the logs at /usr/local/hadoop/logs to find out what happened and add the details to your question.

Comment: The fact that you're prompted for a password means **passwordless** SSH was not setup correctly during Hadoop installation

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a SSH setup with localhost. Please follow these steps and you'll be able to run the namenode.

Go to your system terminal and type:

- > cd(It will redirect you to ~)
- > ssh-keygen(hit enter three times and it will create a .ssh directory in ~)
- > cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys(it will make sure that your localhost is the trusted source and give permission to make
  >   passwordless ssh.)

Then simply run `start-all.sh` and you're all set.